# ¿ Cómo hacer una función de fetch reutilizable con GET y POST?

Tags: javascript, funciones, fetch

estoy tratando de hacer una función reutilizable con la APi fetch.
 lo que quiero conseguir es que cuando el método sea GET solo traiga la información, pero cuando sea POST envíe esa información al servidor, esto es lo que tengo realizado hasta el momento

```
async function getDataUsers(controlador, parametros ='', metodo = '') {

        const opciones = {
            method : metodo,
        };

        const respuesta = await fetch(host_server + controlador, opciones);
        const datos = await respuesta.json();

        if (metodo === 'GET') {
                return datos;
        } else{
                opciones.headers = {'contentType' : 'application/json'};
                opciones.body = JSON.stringify(parametros);
                return datos;
        }

}// End metodo getData
```

Así es como llamo la funcion pasandole estos parametros

```
function getDataUsers('obtenerUsuarios/', '', 'GET');
```

aquí paso el metodo del controlador y el verbo del HTTP, el que esta vacio serian los parametros para enviar información, pero en este caso solo quiero que traiga la información, como en este momento no hay registros en la base de datos, pues no trae nada.

pero este es el resultado que tengo en la consola

```
(index):1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

Este es el código del archivo que hace el llamado

```
class AjaxRequestController{
private $_usuarios;

public function __construct()
{
        $this->_usuarios = new Usuario();
}


public function obtenerUsuarios()
{
        $usuarios = $this->_usuarios->getAllUser();
        if (!empty($usuarios)) {
                $resultado = array('respuesta' => 1, 'data' => $usuarios);
                echo json_encode($resultado);
        } else{
                $resultado = array('respuesta' => 0);
                echo json_encode($resultado);
        }
}// End function obtenerUsuarios
} //End class AjaxRequestController
```

En el momento la respuesta de la base de datos es vacia, no hay registros

Comment: El problema está en la respuesta que viene desde el servidor, que no parece ser un json válido. `Unexpected token <` hace pensar que se te este escapando código HTML u otro en el archivo de servidor que procesa la petición. Pon el código de ese archivo para revisar.

Comment: Como pego el código de mi otro archivo en esta caja de comentarios

Comment: No, en los comentarios no, en la pregunta. Pulsa en [edit]  y agrégalo. Si es demasiado extenso, pon solamente las partes donde recoges la petición, donde armas los datos de la respuesta y donde envías la respuesta al cliente.

Comment: Listo, ya edite la pregunta con lo que dices

Comment: Falta código. ¿Dónde recoges los datos del `$_GET` o del `$_POST`? ¿Dónde llamas a la función `obtenerUsuarios()`? Debes comprender algo muy básico cuando trabajas con código que, desde el cliente, espera un JSON: **no debe salir por pantalla nada más que un JSON**. Si se escapa algo, como un `echo, print...` o un bloque HTML, o un BOM (caracteres ocultos, que no se ven), ya el JSON que recibe el cliente no es válido, porque antes de él habrá algo. Es lo que dice el mensaje de error, antes de tus `echo json_encode($resultado)` **hay algo más, que empieza por `<`** y eso invalida el JSON.

Comment: Si el archivo no es demasiado grande, ponlo completo en la pregunta para revisarlo.

Comment: acabo de colocar, como llamo a la función, pasandole los parámetros

Comment: Me refiero a tu archivo PHP. En ese archivo están saliendo otras cosas por pantalla y hay que revisarlo. No sé si entiendes mis anteriores comentarios ¿?

Comment: Amigo, creo que me estaba faltando algo en el parámetro de la función, no estaba colocando la ruta completa, agregue esto y ya me devuelve lo que responde el controlador
`getDataUsers('AjaxRequest/obtenerUsuarios/', '', 'GET');`

Comment: Ya, pero creo que no has entendido lo que quería decirte. Creo que fallaba porque el servidor emítía un mensaje de error al no recibir bien los datos. Deberías controlar eso en el servidor, porque así verías en el cliente un mensaje claro sobre lo que está ocurriendo. Si revisas, en el servidor, la parte donde recibes la petición, podrás verificarlo. Insisto sobre esto porque lo que te puse más arriba en negrita es fundamental, si  lo comprendes te vas a ahorrar muchas horas comiéndote el coco cuando algo falle con mensajes como `unexpected toke at ...`

Answer (score 0):

No puede retornar datos desde ese método porque recuerde que es una Promise.

Podría ser algo como esto:

```
async function getDataUsers(host_server,metodo, parametros ='') {


switch (metodo) {


    case 'GET':
        return  await fetch(host_server);
        break;

        case 'POST':

            var thisheader
            var thisbody

            switch (parametros) {
                case parametros.headers:
                    thisheader=parametros.headers;
                    break;

                    case parametros.body:
                        thisbody=JSON.stringify(parametros.body)
                        break;

            }

           return await fetch(host_server,{
                headers:thisheader,
                body:thisbody
            });
            break;

            case 'PUT':
                break;

                case 'DELETE':
                    break;

    default:
        break;
}


}


const boton=document.getElementById('buton');

boton.addEventListener('click',async(e)=>{

e.preventDefault();




  await getDataUsers('https://api.hacienda.go.cr/fe/ae?identificacion=127600321123','GET')
    .then((resp)=>console.log(resp))
    .catch((err)=>console.log(err));

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const getDataUsers = ( ruta, method, parametros ) => {
    return  fetch(ruta, method && {
            method,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type':'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(parametros)
        })
}
```

Se usaría algo así:

Caso get con await:

```
const users = await getDataUsers('/users')
console.log(users)  // haces lo que necesitas con tu respuesta
```

Caso get sin await:

```
getDataUsers('/users')
    .then(res=>res.json()) // si envías json. Para otras opciones existe "blob()", "text()", etc.
    .then(res=>console.log(res))  // haces lo que necesitas con tu respuesta
```

Caso post con await:

```
const user = await getDataUsers('/users','POST',{
    idUser: 5
})
console.log(user)  // haces lo que necesitas con tu respuesta
```

Caso post sin await:

```
getDataUsers('/users','POST',{
    idUser: 5,
}).then(res=>res.json()) // si envías json. Para otras opciones existe "blob()", "text()", etc.
.then(res=>console.log(res)) // haces lo que necesitas con tu respuesta
```

Answer (score 0):

gracias por darme sus aportes para este problema, creo que pude lograr que se hiciera, voy a escribir el código del HTML, Javascript y PHP para que puedan ver lo que pude realizar. Si alguno quiere complementar o cambiar alguna linea me encantaría que me evaluaran, muchas gracias.

## VISTA HTML

```
 <div class="contenedor">
<div class="fila">
    <div class="col-xl-12">
        <h1>Fetch Api peticiones a MYSQL</h1>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="fila">
    <div class="col-xl-6 col-l-6 col-m-6 col-s-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="box_container">
            <div class="box_container--header">
                <h2>Formulario envío información.</h2>
            </div>

            <form id="enviar_form">
                <div class="box_container--body">
                        <div class="box_body--input">
                            <input type="text" name="nombres" id="nombres" placeholder="Tus nombres"/>
                        </div>

                        <div class="box_body--input">
                            <input type="text" name="apellidos" id="apellidos" placeholder="Tus apellidos">
                        </div>

                        <div class="box_body--input">
                            <input type="text" name="alias" id="alias" placeholder="Tu alias">
                        </div>

                        <div class="box_body--input">
                            <input type="text" name="nacimiento" id="nacimiento" placeholder="Tu fecha nacimiento">
                        </div>

                        <div class="box_body--input">
                            <input type="text" name="direccion" id="direccion" placeholder="Tu direccion">
                        </div>

                        <div class="box_body--input">
                            <input type="text" name="pais" id="pais" placeholder="Tu pais">
                        </div>

                        <div class="box_body--input">
                            <input type="text" name="telefono" id="telefono" placeholder="Tu telefono">
                        </div>

                        <div class="box_body--input">
                            <input type="text" name="correo" id="correo" placeholder="Tu correo">
                        </div>

                        <div class="box_body--input">
                            <input type="text" name="avatar" id="avatar" placeholder="Tu avatar">
                        </div>
                </div> <!--End box_body-->

                <div class="box_container--footer">
                    <button type="submit">Enviar al servidor</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div> <!--End box-->
    </div> <!--End col-xl-6 -->

    <div class="col-xl-6 col-l-6 col-m-6 col-s-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="box_container">
            <div class="box_container--header">
                <h2>Obtener la información.</h2>
            </div>

            <div class="box_container--body">
                <ul id="load_usuarios"></ul>
            </div> <!--End box-body-->
        </div> <!--End box-->
    </div> <!--End col-xl-6 -->
</div> <!--End fila -->
```

## JAVASCRIPT

```
//VARIABLES
const inputNombres    = document.querySelector('#nombres');
const inputApellidos  = document.querySelector('#apellidos');
const inputAlias      = document.querySelector('#alias');
const inputNacimiento = document.querySelector('#nacimiento');
const inputDireccion  = document.querySelector('#direccion');
const inputPais       = document.querySelector('#pais');
const inputTelefono   = document.querySelector('#telefono');
const inputCorreo     = document.querySelector('#correo');
const inputAvatar     = document.querySelector('#avatar');
const formEnviar      = document.querySelector('#enviar_form');
const userLoadDOM     = document.querySelector('#load_usuarios');

//CLASE DE LA INTERFAZ
class UI {

cargarInformacionFaker() {
        inputNombres.value    = faker.name.findName();
        inputApellidos.value  = faker.name.lastName();
        inputAlias.value      = faker.internet.userName(inputNombres.value);
        let fechaNacimiento   = faker.date.past(50, new Date());
        inputNacimiento.value = fechaNacimiento.getFullYear() + '-' + (fechaNacimiento.getMonth()+1) + '-' + fechaNacimiento.getDate();
        inputDireccion.value  = faker.address.streetAddress();
        inputPais.value       = faker.address.country();
        inputTelefono.value   = faker.phone.phoneNumberFormat();
        inputCorreo.value     = faker.internet.email(inputNombres.value);
        inputAvatar.value     = faker.image.avatar();
} // End cargarInformacion


cargarUsers(users) {

    if (users.respuesta == 0) {
            let div = document.createElement('div');
            div.style.color = '#FFB236';
            userLoadDOM.appendChild(div);
            div.textContent = 'No hay usuarios registrados!';
    }
    else if(users.respuesta == 1){
            //SE CREA LA CLASE
            userLoadDOM.setAttribute('class', 'scroll-ul');
            let listado = '';
            let datos = users.data;

            //RECORRE LA INFORMACION
            datos.forEach(dato => {
                listado += `
                <li>
                        <div class= "usuarios-body">
                            <img src="${dato.avatar_usuario}">
                            <div class="usuarios-content">
                                <p>${dato.nombres_usuario}</p>
                                <span>${dato.correo_usuario}</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </li>`;
            });

            //MUESTRA LA INFORMACION
            return userLoadDOM.innerHTML = listado;
    }
} // ENd metodo cargarUsers


swAlerta(icon, title, text) {
        let alert = Swal.fire({
                                        icon :`${icon}`,
                                        title: `${title}`,
                                        text: `${text}!`
                                    });
        return alert;
}
} //End class UI


//CLASE DE LA INFORMACION USUARIO
class Usuario {

//OBTENER LA INFORMACION POR GET AL SERVIDOR
async obtenerUsuarios() {

        try {
                let response = await Ajax.fetchData('AjaxRequest/obtenerUsuarios/');
                return response;
        } catch(e) {
                console.error('Error => ', e);
        }
} //End metodo obtenerUsuarios

//ENVIAR LA INFORMACION POR POST AL SERVIDOR
async enviarUsuario(form) {
            try {
                    let peticion = await Ajax.fetchData('AjaxRequest/postearUsuarios/', form, 'POST');
                    return peticion;
            } catch(e) {
                    console.error('Error => ', e);
            }

} // enviarInformacion
} //End class Usuario


//CLASE DE LLAMADAS ASYNCRONAS CON FETCH API
class Ajax {

static async fetchData(controlador, parametros, metodo = 'GET') {

        //OPCIONES A LA SOLICITUD DE LA BUSQUEDA
        let opciones = {
                        method : metodo,
                        headers: {
                                'Accept': 'text/plain'
                            }
                };

        //SI EXISTEN PARAMETROS Y EL METODO ES DIFERENTE DE GET AGREGUE AL CUERPO DE LA SOLICITUD LOS PARAMETROS
        if (parametros) {
                if (metodo !== 'GET') {
                        //AGRERAR AL CUERPO DEL OBJETO DE OPCIONES LOS PARAMETROS
                        opciones.body = parametros;


                        //RESPUESTA DEL SERVIDOR
                        let respuesta = await fetch(url_javascript + controlador, opciones);

                        //MUESTRA UN ERROR SI EL CODIGO DE ESTADO NO ES 200
                        if (respuesta.status !== 200) {
                                return {
                                    status: 'error',
                                    'mensaje' : 'El servidor respondió con un estado inesperado.'
                                }
                        }
                        //DEVOLVEMOS LA RESPUESTA
                        let data = await respuesta.json();
                        return data;

                }
        } else{
                //FETCH DEVUELVE UNA PROMESA, POR LO QUE AGREGAMOS LA PALABRA CLAVE AWAIT PARA ESPERAR HASTA QUE SE CUMPLA LA PROMESA
                let respuesta = await fetch(url_javascript + controlador, opciones);

                //MUESTRA UN ERROR SI EL CODIGO DE ESTADO NO ES 200
                if (respuesta.status !== 200) {
                        return{
                            status: 'error',
                            'mensaje' : 'El servidor respondió con un estado inesperado.'
                        }
                }
                //DEVUELVE LA RESPUESTA DE LA INFORMACION
                let datos = await respuesta.json();
                return datos;
        }

}// End metodo getData
}// End class Ajax


//INSTANCIA DE LAS CLASES
const ui   = new UI();
const user = new Usuario();

//CUANDO EL DOM ESTECARGADO
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () =>{

    //CARGA LA INFORMACION EN EL FORMULARIO CON VALORES DE FAKER
    ui.cargarInformacionFaker();

    //CARGA LA INFORMACION DE LOS USUARIOS Y EJECUTA LA DATA PARA MOSTRARLA EN EL UI
    user.obtenerUsuarios()
    .then(users =>{
        ui.cargarUsers(users);
    });
});

//ENVIAMOS DATOS CON EL EVENTO DEL SUBMIT
formEnviar.addEventListener('submit', (e) =>{
    e.preventDefault();
    let form = new FormData(formEnviar);
    user.enviarUsuario(form)
    .then((data) =>{
            if (data.respuesta == 1) {
                ui.swAlerta('success', 'Genial!', data.mensaje)
                .then(() =>{
                        user.obtenerUsuarios()
                        .then(users =>{
                                ui.cargarUsers(users);
                        }) //End then (users)
                }) //End then ()
            } //End if
    }); // End then (data)
    }); // End eventListener (submit)
```

## CONTROLADOR

```
<?php


namespace Mini\Controller;

use Mini\Model\Usuario;

class AjaxRequestController
{
  private $_usuarios;

  public function __construct()
  {
        $this->_usuarios = new Usuario();
  }


  public function obtenerUsuarios()
  {
        $usuarios = $this->_usuarios->getAllUser();
        if (!empty($usuarios)) {
                $resultado = array('respuesta' => 1, 'data' => $usuarios);
                echo json_encode($resultado);
        } else{
                echo json_encode(array('respuesta' => 0));
        }
}// End function obtenerUsuarios


public function postearUsuarios()
{
        $request = $this->_usuarios->postUser($_POST);
        if ($request) {
                $resultado = array('respuesta' => 1, 'mensaje' => 'Los datos fueron guardados');
                echo json_encode($resultado);
        } else{
                echo json_encode($request);
        }
}
} //End class AjaxRequestController
```

## MODELO

```
<?php

namespace Mini\Model;

use Mini\Core\Model;

class Usuario extends Model
{
   public function getAllUser()
   {
        try {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios";
            $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute();
            return $stmt->fetchAll();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return $e->getMessage();
        }
   }// ENd function getAllUser


   public function postUser($data)
   {
        try {
                $sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios (
                nombres_usuario, apellidos_usuario,
                nickName_usuario, fechaNacimiento_usuario,
                direccion_usuario, pais_usuario,
                telefono_usuario, correo_usuario,
                avatar_usuario, fechaCreado_usuario) VALUES(
                :nombres, :apellidos, :nickName, :nacimiento, :direccion,
                :pais, :telefono, :correo, :avatar, :fecha)";
                $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
                $parametros = array(
                    ':nombres'    => $data['nombres'],
                    ':apellidos'  => $data['apellidos'],
                    ':nickName'   => $data['alias'],
                    ':nacimiento' => $data['nacimiento'],
                    ':direccion'  => $data['direccion'],
                    ':pais'       => $data['pais'],
                    ':telefono'   => $data['telefono'],
                    ':correo'     => $data['correo'],
                    ':avatar'     => $data['avatar'],
                    ':fecha'      => date("Y-m-d H:i:s")
                );
                $stmt->execute($parametros);

                //SI AFECTA LA COLUMNA
                if ($stmt->rowCount() == 1) {
                        return true;
                } else{
                        trigger_error("Ocurrio un error", E_USER_ERROR);
                }

        } catch (Exception $e) {
                return $e->getMessage();
        }
   }// End function postUser
}// End class Usuario
```